# jQuery document losing event on page reload

Tags: jquery, events, binding, custom-events

I have problem with custom events bound to document object. My app is divided into few files, here is just an example:

**events.js**

```
(function($){

    $(document).on("updateCommentsView", function(e, data){
        console.debug(e, data);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

**app.js**

```
// some code with functions inside .ready(), then
window.foo(formData, function(r){
    $(document).trigger("updateCommentsView", [{"formData":formData, "response": r}]);
});
```

**The problem**

Whenever I refresh the page (using <kbd>F5</kbd> or refresh button or any other method including `location.reload()` ) my custom binding in `events.js` is gone. But if I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in address bar everything is just fine. Any ideas what is happening there?

Comment: It's not clear what is `window.foo` and how is it called?!

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to provide body of this function. Basically `foo` takes an object as first parameter and callback as second. I can ensure that callback is called.

Comment: That wasn't my question. So on page refresh, `window.foo()` is called but `$(document).trigger("updateCommentsView",...);` doesn't trigger custom bound event???